# pytesseract package not installed in python2.7 & opencv not installed in python3 raspberry pi

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I posted a question related to this staff previously but I didn't get any help.
Today am doing on the same project and in the optical character recognition- simply a digit recognizer system, I used opencv and tesseract (with the python wrapper pytesseract) packages; but since the raspberry pi comes with the two version of python2.7 and python3 opencv installed for the former and pytesseract with the later version's path. when I run my code for the digit recognizer, I got an error since the code uses two packages from two different versions in different path. now I understood the issue and tried to install pytesseract for python2.7 or opencv for python3 , unfortunatlly both not work for me. I explore a lot here in stackoverflow and other blogs, now can I have any better solution.
sorry for the code part, this is due to I run on separate desktop and not possible to add any code  and screenshots.
thanks.

Comment: you can install opencv for python3, what was the issue with that?

Comment: don't start new projects with Python2

Comment: yes, I tried to install by entering the command "python3 -m pip install opencv-python" but it stayed a long time by loading over "Building wheel for opencv-python(project.toml) ...|" .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I hand the same problem a few weeks aog. The official [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html) helped me a lot. Just follow the "Building OpenCV from source" section.